# Eclipse is showing all the android layout items as they had gravity "right"

Tags: android, eclipse, layout, textview, gravity

This is a screenshot to illustrate what is happening

[image: Screenshot eclipse layout problem]

As you see in the image, everything is shown to the right, even if I change the gravity field to "center". The thing is that when I test it on my phone it is shown as it should. But it is tough to be always running the app to design it.

Does anybody know the reason? 
Thank you very much!

Comment: can you share your layout?

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to post images can you vote me so that I can post it please?

Comment: send me in mail so i can check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am facing the same issue, but *only* with Api Lvl 17.

**Try selecting a different Target.**

[image: target]

Comment: It works now! But my solution was different than yours. I was supporting Api Lvl 18 and when I changed to Api Lvl 17.
I figure why does it happen, because I have a Nexus 7 with this Api Lvl and it works great

Comment: @mxmolins I think it's a problem at eclipse start-up. the first selected Level get's displayed wrong